# Comparing partial equality with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

If I have an expected value:

```
{
  "name": "widgets"
  "count": 4,
  "description": "cool widgets",
}
```

And a return value from an API:

```
{
  "name": "widgets",
  "count": 10,
  "description": "cool widgets",
}
```

Is there a general way to write tests in pytest that will consider any value to be equal for certain attributes? I would like to be able to write something like:

```
{
  "name": "widgets",
  "count": ...,
  "description": "cool widgets",
}
```

And have the ellipsis mean "any value here should be considered equal". This is of course a trivial example, and I could just do something like:

```
assert all(expected[k] == returned[k] for k in ['name', 'description'])
```

But that quicklky becomes untenable with nested structures.

Comment: This isn't built into pytest in any way. Personally, I would write some helper function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the key names in some way I believe. If there are fewer keys that you don't care about than care about, then you could do the reverse:

```py
assert all(expected[k] == returned[k] for k in list(set(expected.keys()) - set('count')))
```